# how to run multiple functions parallel in python

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I want to receive serial data and depending on the data want to make announcement. my monitor function will continuously monitor serial data. But I am facing a problem that when i am announcing something then after completion of announcement serial data is monitored and the process going slow. I want to monitor serial data continuously and want to made the announcement parallel. Is threading is the best option?? how to handle it?

```
def announce(data):
   subprocess.call('espeak',data)

while 1:

    receiveddata= xbee.readline()  
    if receiveddata=='a1':
        announce("i am ok in room1")
    if receiveddata=='b2':
        announce("Urgently attend room 1")
```

Comment: Use the threading package, one thread to monitor the serial data, one thread to fork the subprocess. Use Queue to communicate between the two threads will be nice enough.

Comment: Sir I am new in threading if you kindly provide me an example it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @KenCheung I think your suggestion is FAR better than the answer provided below by Torxed: just create the announcing thread ONCE and let the main thread pass the received data to the announcing thread via a queue. Why don't you write it as a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread

def announce(data):
    subprocess.call('espeak',data)

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        if receiveddata=='a1':
            announce("i am ok in room1")
        if receiveddata=='b2':
            announce("Urgently attend room 1")
        # at the end of run() the process will die.

while 1:
    receiveddata = xbee.readline()
    thread_handle = worker(receiveddata)
    thread_handle.start() # <- This starts the thread but keeps on going
```

Here's a skeleton framework that you can use in order to achieve paralell processing in Python. It's not complete nor is it perfect, but it will give you a start and it will solve your initial problem.

There's tons of "best practices" for threading and stuff, i'll leave google to explain and find those because there will always be a better solution than what i can produce in one short answer here.

### Good to know:

I honored the fact that you were new to threading in python.

But as discussed in the comments below, this will be a resource demanding solution if you have a a lot of data on the serial port (which will `create thread` -> `do work` -> `die`).

There are more effective threading solutions (such as keeping a thread alive throughout the program and calling a function in the class that announces instead). But this is the bare minimum that you'll need in order to get started.

### Once you're comfortable with threads

I'll leave these links here for you to experiment and evolve your threading knowledge from this very basic example above:

- [Threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190206/threading-in-python)
- [How to call a function on a running Python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033818/how-to-call-a-function-on-a-running-python-thread)
- [In Python threading, how I can I track a thread's completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440667/in-python-threading-how-i-can-i-track-a-threads-completion)
- http://blog.boa.nu/2012/10/python-threading-example-creating-pingerpy.html
- http://www.python-course.eu/threads.php

**Working with queues**

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html
- [How to call a function on a running Python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033818/how-to-call-a-function-on-a-running-python-thread) (Linked it twice on purpose)
- http://lonelycode.com/2011/02/04/python-threading-and-queues-and-why-its-awesome/

Comment: please follow [PEP-8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming conventions.

Comment: Where is `receiveddata` defined/assigned?

Comment: @Pynchia `data = xbee.readline()`, i simply renamed the `recieveddata` to `data` and passed that to the class (that will become a thread).

Comment: @Pynchia I'm sorry but i consider single word classes ugly when they begin with a capital letter. It's a matter of taste and i respect that the majority of people think this is awesome.. But it's like religion, don't force it down my throat if I don't like it, it hinders my productivity trying to focus on things that are not important to me. It's selfish I know, but if i'm to be able to do my every day work, help people here and be a tutor I will do what I feel comfortable with. I do however normally teach people to follow the PEP guidelines, I just don't apply them to quick answers.

Comment: See my comment to the question above. Personally I think there is a more elegant solution than creating a thread upon every reception, which is overkill. This is a classic producer-consumer situation.

Comment: @Pynchia Absolutely, creating a "Living thread" with a neat function to call for the ammouncement would be ideal, but then you'd need a thread govenor that terminates the thread accordingly and some other things. This is the most basic framework I could come up with that wasn't a massive PITA to take in for a first-timer as the user explained himself to be. I couldn't make the code easier to understand without him asking more questions (considering you even asked where `recieveddata` is defined when it should be obvious told me that this code was enough to begin with).